# Ways to count lattice paths with backtracking

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been studying lattice paths, and I stumbled across this problem.

Given a rectangular grid with (0,0) and (m,n) as its corners, find the number paths possible from (0,0) to (m,n). There are several rules, of course.

1. The object must stay within the boundaries of the grid, inclusive.
2. The object must go either up one unit, or to the right one unit for each step. However ...
3. The object may choose to go down one unit once in the entire path, or not at all.

I started this problem with the formula:

C(n,k) = Choose k from n combinations

Number of paths = [number of paths without going down] + [number of path with going down]

Number of paths = C(m + n, n) + n * C(m + n + 2, m)

Is this the correct formula?

Part 2:

What would the formula be if object would not be allowed to land on an arbitrary point, (i, j), if given that 0 < i < m and 0 < j < n?

Comment: Your description is not clear. Obviously steps of type 2 can be made repeatedly, but if you allow the same for steps of type 3 you get an infinite number of solutions. Do you mean that one has the right, at most one time during the path, to include a step that goes one unit down or stays at the same point?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen My interpretation is that at most one down step may be made, and it can't be made on the bottom edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C(m+n,n)$ counts the number of ways without a down move.  For paths with a down move, there must be a total of $m+n+2$ moves because you need another up to counter the down.  I will take $m$ to be the horizontal direction of your grid.  I would count those by first changing the down to another up.  This gives us a path to $(m,n+2)$, of which there are $C(m+n+2,m)$.  Then we can choose any one of the ups to be the down except the first or last.  If we flip the first or last we go outside the grid, so there are $nC(m+n+2,m)$ paths including a down, for a final total of $C(m+n,n)+nC(m+n+2,m)$